# Outlook object model

Tags: powershell, outlook, com

I am writing a PowerShell script to share calendars.
The script works, but the thing is I can't edit the permissions and the default is "Availability Only". I want to give "Full Details".

P.S. - Can't use native Exchange cmdlets.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$Calendar = $Outlook.Session.Session.Folders.Item(1)
$Calendar = $Calendar.Folders.Item("Calendar")

$CalendarShare = $namespace.CreateSharingItem($Calendar)
$CalendarShare.To = "somemail@mail.com"
$CalendarShare.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this using Outlook, VS using native Exchange cmdlets to set the ACL?

You just grant the Calendar permission role of Reviewer, which is the same thing that provided when trying to set 'Full Details' calendar permission.

For example.

[Add-MailboxFolderPermission for every Mailbox](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/2930b4ab-bfae-4f91-ad1b-1ada8eeb2e10)

[Set-CalendarPermissions](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/19b98a56-42aa-4695-b07c-335d8322b64e) # of course this is a script from the gallery, but it's using Exchange cmdlets.

It's really doing stuff like this...

```
# Review permissions
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity 'username:\Calendar'

# Set permissions
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -identity 'username:\Calendar' -user 'personalassistant' -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is unavailable to me... (Can't use native Exchange cmdlets)

Comment: @Roee Ziv : are you sure? Even users have (by default) permissions to do Get-Mailbox (only returns their own mailbox) or Add-MailboxFolderPermission. Just checked this on my 365 tenant with a regular user account and importing a PS Session gives me 154 cmdlets to use (even in Exchange 2010 you had a lot of CMDlets available to users).

Comment: As for 'Unfortunately, this option is unavailable to me... (Can't use native Exchange cmdlets)', you need permissions on the user's mailboxes to do this, if you do not have that permission, there is nothing you can do, regardless of language you try to use. This is an Exchange Admin control. So, you have to get your Exchange Admin to set this ACL.